# Compositor not showing image layers, how do I fix this?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

I haven't really messed with compositor before trying a tutorial. The focus of the tutorial came out fine, a visualizer for audio, but there's some images I'd like to be visible as well.

The uploader said to just add an image into the scene, but they just aren't showing up.
I'm not really sure what to try, since compositor is still foreign to me, and I've googled numerous times with no luck for what I'm doing.

The layout is meant to look like this (excluding the visualizer area):
[image: A screenshot of the Blender Layout tab. It includes a background, a logo, a chat box, and a region for an audio visualizer.]

But is instead showing up and rendering like this:
[image: A screenshot of the Blender Compositing tab. It shows a node tree and a light grey background with a visualizer line and some text.]

Here's a better image of my nodes, both Geometry and Compositing.
[image: A screenshot of a Geometric Node Tree.]
[image: A screenshot of a Compositing node tree.]

I hope this was coherent, and I hope someone can help (: